# Android Certificate Changed?

Tags: android, certificate, apk, google-play

I recently formatted my computer and updated to Windows 7. I backed up my keystore and tried to sign my apk with it but it gave me an error that said my certificate expires in 22yrs. which is just shy of what the market requires to upload the apk. So now I am stuck not being able to update my app...

How did this happen?

Is there a way to extend the lifetime of certificates so that I can update my app?

Is there a way to verify this certificate against an old apk that has been uploaded to the market so that I can be sure I am trying to sign with the same certificate and I didn't have a mix up?

[Error Pic](http://7842005178648529855-a-1802744773732722657-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/rgrandy/home/Untitled.png?attachauth=ANoY7coTpb0WLPu6fd154Anh44Dff94VhvS_I4vMpELBTwZAajjkNVPu5Lt-f57FltleNooyeMfO7fiE0sqlP0ap51ti1MgJbEoHa9iPIvbWM7k5DY1u4sAs8artBn3k2tVoFIcV2025r6jHEwb__dV9Rblg3yD-QBMgyx2Nn4Xv3-cYV89nYNF2edp40In7M1Kmp2HSTODD&attredirects=0)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to verify this
>   certificate against an old apk that
>   has been uploaded to the market so
>   that I can be sure I am trying to sign
>   with the same certificate and I didn't
>   have a mix up?

You might get enough info to confirm that via:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
```

You might also try [signing outside of Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode) to see if that changes matters.